# Semantically linking to code snippets

Tags: html, language-agnostic, xhtml, semantics, code-snippets

## Question

What's the most **lightweight**, **semantic**, and over-all **best** way of referencing snippets of code within XHTML 1.1?

---

### Claim

Snippets of code within HTML are not semantically proper. Snippets (ideally) would only be *referenced* or *linked* (using `<object>`, `<a>`, etc.), not embedded, escaped, and styled in full.

---

### Rationale

- Let **browsers render** code snippets

  - Having many custom server-side implementations tells me it should be standardized
  - Browsers can have plug-ins for copy+paste, download, etc.

    - Seems to me this is where it belongs (not in Javascript)
- **Why not use** `<code>`

  - **Escaped code is ugly**
  - We render it *for* the client
  - No semantic representation of the language itself (MIME type would be nice)
- **Javascript is functionality**, not presentation.

  - Syntax needs to be **portable** (i.e. *no proprietary functionality*)
  - No need for hacked-together solutions

---

### Illustration

```
Resource      Tag    Actual resource              Alternative format
Image         img    An image located on server   `alt` attribute
Source code   ?      A file containing code       `code` tag? `a` link?
```

---

### Example solution

code_sample.php is in the same directory as an HTML page containing the following:

```
<a href="code_sample.php" type="text/x-php">
  Example of widget creation
</a>
```

- Pros

  - **Semantically uses title** to describe the source code being referenced
  - **Degradation**: non-compliant browsers render a link to the associated content
  - Also, **LinkType** seems like a potentially good attribute for specifying "Code Snippet"

    - http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/abstraction.html#dt_LinkTypes
- Cons

  - Not **semantic enough**? Seems wrong to replace hyperlinks with source code for presentation
  - `<object>` might be better, but wouldn't degrade as nicely.

---

**What's the most lightweight, semantic, and over-all best way of referencing snippets of code within XHTML 1.1?**

Comment: Do you want the code snippets included in the page or linked to? Your title says _"linking"_ but your question says _"presenting code snippets"_.

Comment: Well... linked, but not necessarily using `<a>`. Good catch though, updated. Thanks!